# WPF Datatrigger on button based on datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, triggers

Currently, I have the following datatrigger:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ScheduleDataGrid, Path=HasItems}"
                        Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="false"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and I have two buttons that adds/deletes a row in a datagrid

```
<Button Name="BtnAddPoint" Content="Add" Width="70" Margin="10 0 10 0" Click="BtnAddSchedule_Click"></Button>
<Button Name="BtnDeletePoint" Content="Delete" Width="70" Click="BtnDeleteSchedule_Click"></Button>
```

I have two questions.

Currently, the above trigger disables both of the button when I only want it to disable the delete button. Setting the targetname of the setter to the delete button doesn't work. Can I make the trigger target a particular button?

Also, I'd like the delete button to be only enabled when a grid item is selected rather than checking for the item count. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Style` with key if you want to assign it to appropriate button:

```
<Style x:Key="DeleteButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="True" />
    <Style.Triggers>              
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ScheduleDataGrid, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>            
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

In `BtnDeletePoint` button you should add style:

```
<Button Name="BtnAddPoint" Content="Add" Width="70" Margin="10 0 10 0" Click="BtnAddSchedule_Click"></Button>
<Button Name="BtnDeletePoint" Content="Delete" Width="70" Click="BtnDeleteSchedule_Click" Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}"></Button>
```

Instead of checking `HasItems` and writing another trigger to check if grid has selected item, you can write trigger and check if `SelectedItem` is null. `SelectedItem` property gives you information if grid has items and if user selected one of them.

Comment: Good call on `SelectedItem` is `{x:Null}` trigger - didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

If both `Button`s share the same `Style` and therefore have the same `Trigger`, then they are both going to be disabled under the same circumstances (in this case, when the `DataGrid` has 0 items).

In order to disable the Delete `Button` under different circumstances you will need to create a separate `Style` with a different `Trigger` and apply that style to BtnDeletePoint.  Since I don't see you setting the `Style` in the declaration of the buttons, I would guess the trigger belongs to an Implicit Style for `Button`, so you'll need to assign an `x:Key` to the new style so that you can assign it to your delete button:

```
<Style x:Key="DeleteButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <!-- Setters -->
    <!-- Triggers -->
</Style>

<Button Name="BtnDeletePoint" Style="{DynamicResource DeleteButtonStyle}" Content="Delete" Width="70" Click="BtnDeleteSchedule_Click"/>
```

As for the trigger to enable the delete button when only a single item is selected, if you don't want to use the `Count` of the `SelectedItems` property on the `DataGrid`, then you would need to use a `Converter` to determine the selection state of the grid - there are no other `DependencyProperties` on the `DataGrid` that I'm aware of that will provide you that information.

Also, I'm not sure of the context without more of the code, but don't believe you want a `DataTrigger` in this case - you should be fine with a standard `Trigger`.